# android full screen mode in phonegap

Tags: eclipse, android-emulator, cordova

When I am running android simulator on eclipse [Phonegap] it launch itself in full screen. It become difficult for me to see the top and the bottom of the emulator.

How can I set the emulator size to small ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to append the parameter `-scale <scale factor>` to the Emulator launch parameters. In eclipse, put it in the field "Additional Emulator Command Line Options" within the Run Configuration.

Allowed `scale factors` are those between 0.1 and 3, although the most common will probably be -scale 0.5 .

way 1 :

Here can help U: Menu->Windows->Android SDK and AVG manager->Choose your AVD then select Edit button, in Line Skin you choose HVGA for Built-in or custom your size resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Select "Window" in the menu, then click the SDK option and create a new profile. Then it will ask you to launch. Select on scale and define your own width and height.

After you restart your Eclipse, it will be in custom mode.

Answer (score 0):

Once the emulator is launched enter this:

```
adb emu window scale 0.5
```

Just tested it with a Cordova/Phonegap Android emulator :)